# Django: modifying data with user input through custom template tag?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Is it possible to modify data through custom template tag in Django? More specifically, I have a model named Shift whose data I want to display in a calendar form. I figured using a custom inclusion tag is the best way to go about it, but I also want users to be able to click on a shift and buy/sell the shift (thus modifying the database). My guess is that you can't do this with an inclusion tag, but if I were to write a different type of custom template tag from the ground up, would this be possible? If so, can you direct me to a few resources that address how to write such a tag?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of logic does not belong in a template tag. It belongs in a view that will respond to AJAX requests and return a JSONResponse. You'll need some javascript to handle making the request based on the input as well.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I am not very familiar with using AJAX or JSON, especially in conjunction with Django though. Could you please briefly explain what the workflow would be to write this view? I tried searching the web but it's harder to find than I'd expected..

Comment: The ajax view is like any other, except that it'll return a response tailored to be handled by javascript. Either it'll be a basic html template or some JSON. Here's some links that go into more detail: https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/ http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/ajax.html

Comment: A quick followup question: I understand I need an AJAX view to perform such actions as buying/selling shifts that modify the database, but in order to _display_ the shifts in the database, would I still need to use templatetags? How would I integrate both in one webpage?

Comment: That's just a normal view and you wouldn't need a template tag to do that. You just create your view and the template. If that sounds like gibberish, then you should go through the django tutorial(s) to have a basic understanding of how to create views. If you don't feel like you need to, then here's an example of how you could write part of your template to display the shifts. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/#use-the-template-system

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify myself, I wanted to use custom template tags (specifically the ones from [link](https://github.com/eldarion/kairios)django-kairios) to view shifts in a calendar. But yeah, I will try to look into more docs to see what I can do.

Comment: Create as new question with more details. I am not following what you're trying to do.

Comment: Just did! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31507308/using-fullcalendar-in-django @schillingt