# How to change select element that is neither class nor id in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, queryselector

So I'm trying to change the value `&nbsp;` below with JavaScript.

```
<td class="fc-day fc-fri fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2020-05-15">
    <div>
        <div class="fc-day-number">15</div>
        <div class="fc-day-content">
            <div style="border: black 1px solid;">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
<td>
```

This is a pre-designed template, and I cannot directly make changes to it. So I'm trying to use JavaScript but can't figure out a way to do it.
For the record, this is a calendar template, so there are lots of `.fc-day`s. What distinguishes each `.fc-day` is the `data-date` property. 
I very much appreciate your help in advance :)

Comment: Oh right. That </td> is a typo. And thanks for the advice. This works, but partly. So when I click 'inspect' in my page, I can see that the code in my <script> tag has changed. Works perfectly in there. But the actual code in <body> tag hasn't changed. What is the problem?

Comment: Thanks. Is there any possibility that the library I'm using (```django-fullcalendar```) has somehow blocked making changes to its template?

Comment: It is possible that this is a generated element which is managed by a library. I see that you try to modify the fc-day-content innerHtml but I really think that there should be a method in the calendar widget to handle and therefore modify this content instead of trying to manipulate it with JS after it is rendered. It is possible you need to rerender the element or update that rendered element. Can you show a live example or which library or calender widget you use?

Comment: Well, I'm using ```django-fullcalendar``` library. And all I have in my template is ```{% calendar %}```.  When I looked at the code through 'inspect', I found out that the part that I want to change is written in the code above, and tried to manipulate with JS. I see that change is made in the <script> tag in my webpage, but no change in the actual code in the <body> tag.

Comment: Then indeed you will have to do it in another fashion. You need a data object to add content to calendar elements. Also make sure that editable option is set to True.

Comment: You can also make a custom template yourself in Python and actually this is using jQuery FullCalender plugin so you it would be best to follow the documentation of this. Read up on this question regarding FullCalendar and customizing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31507308/using-fullcalendar-in-django

Comment: Oh thank you very much. I'll give it a try :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214143/discussion-between-bojoer-and-ryan-oh).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using firstChild if you can use the class name of the parent div and if the element is always the first element inside that div so try:

```
const el = document.querySelector(".fc-day-content").firstChild.innerHtml;
```

Comment: If you want all elements on the page you should use querySelectorAll() and loop it to get each element. You can also specify the data-date="someValue" if you need one or more specific elements that have a certain date.

Answer (score 0):

Use a selector that matches the date you want, then select the appropriate DIV within it.

```js
document.querySelector(".fc-day[data-date='2020-05-15'] .fc-day-content > div").innerHTML = 'new contents';
```

```html
<table>
  <td class="fc-day fc-fri fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2020-05-15">
    <div>
      <div class="fc-day-number">15</div>
      <div class="fc-day-content">
        <div style="border: black 1px solid;">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <td>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works, but partly. So when I click 'inspect' in my page, I can see that the code in my <script> tag has changed. Works perfectly in there. But the actual code in <body> tag hasn't changed. What is the problem?

Comment: I needed quotes around the attribute value in the selector. It works now. I got an error when I tried my original code, didn't you?

Answer (score 0):

I have made a workable JS Fiddle which will help you for the reference.

```
function test(){
 document.querySelector(".fc-day-content > div").innerHTML = 'new contents';
}
```

Please visit https://jsfiddle.net/q48frcgp/